# Что нужно вместо двоеточия?

Tags: пунктуация

"Мы делаем этот проект для Вас! Мы делаем его для детей, у которых мечта: жить!"

Answer (score 1):

**"Жить"**- это **определение**, **выраженное инфинитивом** и имеющее **пояснительное** значение. Поэтому перед ним ставится тире. В неполном придаточном "...у которых мечта - жить" подлежащее "мечта", сказуемое "есть" выпущено. Ср.:  "...у которых есть (=имеется) ***мечта КАКАЯ? - жить***".

(http://www.licey.net/russian/syntax/r1_2_3_4):
***1. Определение, выраженное неопределённой формой глагола (инфинитивом), обособляется (с помощью тире), если оно имеет пояснительное значение и перед ним можно поставить слова а именно. В устной речи таким определениям-инфинитивам предшествует пауза:
Но прекрасен данный жребий – просиять и умереть (Брюсов).***

1. Определение, выраженное неопределённой формой глагола (инфинитивом), *не обособляется, если оно образует вместе с именем существительным единое словосочетание. Обычно такие определения стоят в середине предложения и произносятся без пауз:*

*Мысль жениться на Олесе всё чаще и чаще приходила мне в голову (Куприн).*

**1) Определения-инфинитивы выделяются с помощью тире, а не запятой или двоеточия.**
2) Если обособленное определение, выраженное инфинитивом, находится в середине предложения, то оно отделяется при помощи тире с двух сторон.
*Каждый из них решал этот вопрос – уехать или остаться – для себя, для своих близких (Кетлинская).*
Но если по условиям контекста после определения должна стоять запятая, то второе тире обычно опускается.
*Так как оставался один выбор – потерять армию и Москву или одну Москву, то фельдмаршал должен был выбрать последнее (Л. Толстой).*

Answer (score 0):

Там надо тире ставить, т.к. жить - сказуемое, а мечта - существительное в им. падеже

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, какая связь между сказуемым ЖИТЬ и дополнением У КОТОРЫХ? Такая связь должна быть, потому что дополнение должно быть связано со сказуемым. Сравните: "У меня выходной" или "У них конфликт". Просто сказуемое ЕСТЬ (ИМЕЕТСЯ) здесь опущено (но подразумевается). А ЖИТЬ - определение.

Answer (score 0):

А почему надо заменять? Если учитывать эмоциональность всего высказывания - можно отнести его к художественному приему. Напоминает Цветаеву, у которой и "вложенные" двоеточия встречаются.